# Pre Populate input field in `FormGroup` - Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am using Angular2 - Reactive Forms. Everything works fine until i want to show a pre-populated value in one of fields in Form.

**Scenario:** There are multiple buttons on a page and each button opens up a form with fields as

1. Name
2. Email
3. Message
4. Product Code --> Value for this shall be prepopulated as per item code from service.

> Failing Scenario: Product Code input value turns to null.

TS Code:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
queryForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private _productService: ProductService, fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.queryForm = fb.group({
        'name': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])],
        'email': [
            null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]
        ],
        'message': [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])],
        'pcode': [
            null
        ],
    })
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of product">
<form action="#" [formGroup]="queryForm" 
 (ngSubmit)="submitForm(queryForm.value)" method="post" 
  novalidate="" class="text-left note" id="f_{{item.productId}}">
    [ .... rest of the fields ...]
    <div class="form-group hidden">
          <input type="hidden " class="form-control " id="pcode " name="pcode" 
        formControlName="pcode" [value]="item.productCode" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
           <button type="submit" class="btn1" [disabled]="!queryForm.valid">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Note that your question mentioned that you're using template driven forms - but FormGroup, FormBuilder etc are for reactive forms - meaning that the creation and management of your forms are driven from your component code, not your template - so which approach are you intending to use: template or reactive?

Comment: the question above might seem like it's irrelevant, but unless you know what you're doing, mixing the two approaches will just confuse you

Comment: Oops.. Reactive forms

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:** As we found out, you are needing a `formArray` instead of a single `formControl`. So declare that when you build form:

```ts
this.queryForm = this.fb.group({
  arrayOfData: this.fb.array([]) // name a proper name to array
})
```

You can use `setValue` or `patchValue` when you have received your data, where you iterate the response and patch the values to your form array. Call `patchValues`-method in your callback (subscribe).

```ts
patchValues() {
  const control = <FormArray>this.queryForm.get('arrayOfData');
  this.items.forEach(x => {
    control.push(this.patchValue(x.first_name, x.pcode))
  })
}

patchValue(name, code) {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: [name],
    pcode: [code]
  })    
}
```

In your template iterate the formarray and also remember to set the formgroupname (which is the index):

```html
<div formArrayName="arrayOfData">
  <div *ngFor="let code of queryForm.get('arrayOFData').controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>Name: </label>
      <input formControlName="name" /><br>
      <label>Product Code: </label>
      <input formControlName="pcode" /><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

**Original answer:**

You should always set the form values in the component, not the template. You can use `patchValue` or `setValue`, when you have received the value from the service... so you can do this e.g inside the callback (subscribe):

```html
this.myService.getSomeData()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.item = data;
     this.queryForm.patchValue({pcode: this.item.productCode})
  });
```

Then you do not need to use `[value]="item.productCode"` in your form, this value is set with the form control instead.

Comment: Where do i need to subscr\ibe this ?

Comment: Well, this is just an example, you said you get your value from the service, so when you have received your value for `item`, then use patchValue to set the value you have gotten :)

Comment: Then this pcode will be mapped for every form that i have on the page?

Comment: *"every form I have on the page"*, not sure what you mean?? BTW, updated answer with a demo.

Comment: it means that service returns bunch of products and each corresponding to each product there are multiple forms. So each form shall hold value of pcode as returned from service for each product

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. You need to show code, otherwise it's impossible to help you. Please fork the plunker and reproduce the issue there, so maybe I can help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141869/discussion-between-gags-and-ajt-82).

Comment: `http://plnkr.co/edit/3aTYorayo1gwboBeKIcH?p=preview` .. Forked the plunker... if i have multiple pcode in json.. then there is no value

Comment: You need to iterate and create a formarray if you have several fields. FormControl works only with one value.

Comment: Yup.. that is what i am seeking for... any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Updated answer, now should be what you want :)

Comment: why is the reason to create the formArray inside a FormGroup? if you only need a formArray use a formArray directly

Comment: @Eliseo, sure, if you only need an FormArray. OP is using a form with other fields, why would we create a separate formarray for that as the form already exists?