# Reuse model driven form inside an ngFor loop

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In our component, we display a list of users. On each users "line", using a ngFor loop, we have a form to handle the user modification.

I tried to setup a model driven form to be applied to my HTML at each ngFor iteration, to be bound to the particular user.

**My problem is, due to the fact the [formGroup] is identical for all my users, the form value are kept from one user to another... Is there a way to handle this case in Angular 2model driven forms?**

Here are the important parts of files:

#### Component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.usersList = [...]; // My Array of users retrieved from the service
   this.initDynamicForm();
}

initDynamicForm() {
  let name = '';
  let email = '';

  this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [ name, Validators.required ],
    email: [ email, Validators.required ]
  });
}
```

#### Component HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let user of usersList">
    <p>{{ user.name }} - {{ user.email }}</p>

    <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="dynamicForm" (ngSubmit)="editUserDetails(user.id);">
        Name: <input type="text" formControlName="name">
        Email: <input type="text" formControlName="email">

        <button type="submit">Edit User</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You want a formArray :)

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43449064/6294072

Comment: Thank, will definitely have a look as it seems the stuff I need